# Cassandra TTL and gc_grace_seconds

Tags: cassandra

Using Cassandra 3.0:

If all of my columns have a (default or otherwise) TTL and I **never** delete a column, but overwrites happen maybe 2-3 times a day, can I set `gc_grace_seconds = 0`?

Note: The TTL of a columns, even after being overwritten, always points to the same point in time. E.g. March 10, 2017

Will I run into issues when a node goes down?

I know if I deleted a column and a node goes down and does not come up before gc_grace_seconds, I will have zombie column. "Logic" says this shouldn't be a problem unless the overwritten column has a different TTL.